# I'm having problems specifying my own java.awt.printjob.PrinterJob implementation

Tags: java, printing, awt

I am using Java 1.6 on an embedded platform that has no real concept of printing, so I'm trying to implement my own.  I'm trying to provide my own implementation of classes paralleling what would be provided by Oracle for Java to use to print on a Unix or Windows platform, but I'm having problems.  The java.awt.print.PrinterJob class is used to obtain a PrinterJob instance, which is platform specific.  On Windows PrinterJob.getPrinterJob() returns an instance of sun.print.Win32PrintJob, which is created in PrinterJob.getPrinterJob() using reflection on the system property java.awt.printerjob.  Once you have an instance of PrinterJob you can use other API methods to print as has been answered several times on this website.  I tried running with -Djava.awt.printerjob=initialization.CustomPrinterJob which is my implementation of PrinterJob but the system property seems to be reset in when the Virtual Machine starts, so I change it in my code using System.setProperty("java.awt.printerjob", "initialization.CustomPrinterJob") but doing that causes PrinterJob.getPrinterJob() to have a ClassNotFoundException, where I would have expected it to use my code.  I can create an instance of that object using reflection, so I'm not sure why the java.awt.print.PrinterJob.getPrinterJob method can't.  I've posted my code below, if anyone could help or has any ideas I would really be grateful.

MyPrinterJobExample.java:

```
package initialization;

import java.awt.AWTError;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

public class MyPrinterJobExample {

    // Copied from PrinterJob.getPrinterJob()
    public static PrinterJob getPrinterJob() {
        // Copied and Pasted the body of PrinterJob.getPrinterJob() Here
    }

    /**
     * The Entry Point into this Application
     * @param args the Command Line Arguments, which should be none
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Override some System Properties
            System.setProperty("java.awt.printerjob", "initialization.CustomPrinterJob");
            System.out.println("java.awt.printerjob: " + System.getProperty("java.awt.printerjob", null));

            // Direct Creation (works)
            PrinterJob p = new CustomPrinterJob();

            // Reflection Creation (works)
            PrinterJob p2 = (PrinterJob)Class.forName("initialization.CustomPrinterJob").newInstance();

            // Copied from PrinterJob.getPrinterJob (works?)
            PrinterJob p3 = MyPrinterJobExample.getPrinterJob();

            // PrinterJob.getPrinterJob (fails)
            PrinterJob p4 = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomPrinterJob.java:

```
package initialization;

public class CustomPrinterJob extends PrinterJob {
    // Assume the Necessary Abstract Functions are Implemented
}
```

Output:

```
java.awt.printerjob: initialization.CustomPrinterJob
Creating CustomPrinterJob
Creating CustomPrinterJob
Creating CustomPrinterJob
java.awt.AWTError: PrinterJob not found: initialization.CustomPrinterJob
        at java.awt.print.PrinterJob$1.run(PrinterJob.java:66)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.print.PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(PrinterJob.java:59)
        at initialization.MyPrinterJobExample.main(MyPrinterJobExample.java:52)
```

Comment: I guarantee that only a tiny proportion of the code you have posted is relevant. Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and remove as much code as possible while still showing the problem, then post that code here. What you have done is just lazy and I for one am not going to wade through it.

Comment: Bohemian, I made some edits, hopefully they are to your liking.

Comment: That is actually much better and a good SSCCE. My best is guess is that the `PrinterJob` class you've copied from is not the same one that's getting executed. Check your classpath for jars that contain the class. The easiest way is to rename all the jars to .zip and unzip them them search for filename

Comment: @Bohemian I looked through the jar files, which there aren't many, only the JDK provided ones, and the only place I can find a java.awt.print.PrinterJob class file is in Java provided rt.jar.  That is the one I was looking at initially to copy the PrinterJob.getPrinterJob method.  The only reason I copied it was to try to troubleshoot why it was throwing an exception, but when I copy it to my own source file it works fine.  The source for this is in the JDK/src.zip file.

Comment: Get the source and debug it. Find out exactly what logic path is being taken. It could be a security issue perhaps related to the classloader

Comment: @Bohemian thanks for your help, but I've decided to take a different approach.  Since I have to write socket code to communicate with my printers, and I'm only printing text it's waste of time for me to figure out why this isn't working.  If someone knew why I was having problems here because they have tried the same thing that would have been great, but debugging the API code is too time intensive for this task.